# Atribuir href via jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um elemento  no meu Layout e estou tentando setar o href via jquery, mas o mesmo não vai. O condigo está na minha index. 
Segue o código:

**Layout**

```
<div class="three wide column dindex">
        <div class="ui left fixed vertical blue inverted menu dmenu">
            <div class="ui containe">
                <h3 class="item">Menu Principal</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="ui container firstmenu">
                <a id="itemsMD" class="item dalink menus" href="~/EAD/EDisciplinas/Conteudo">Material Didático</a>
                <!--<a id="items" class="item" title="curso" href="#curso">Notas</a>-->
                <a id="itemsA" class="item dalink menus">Avisos</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui container secondmenu">
                <a id="itemsP" class="item dalink" href="~/EAD/EPrincipal">Disciplinas</a>
                <a id="itemsS" class="item dalink" href="~/EAD/EAccount/Sair">Sair</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Index - Código Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    /* Atribui ID */
    $("#itemsA").attr("href", "@ViewBag.IDDisciplina");
    /* CRIA A HREF */
    $('<a>', {
        class: 'item dalink',
        href: '~/EAD/EDisciplinas/Forum/@ViewBag.IDDisciplina',
        text: 'Forum de Discussão'
    }).appendTo('.firstmenu');
});
```

Ele cria o a href mas fica da seguinte forma: http://localhost:32322/EAD/EDisciplinas/Index/~/EAD/EDisciplinas/Forum/1

Mas eu gostaria que ficasse somente 
http://localhost:32322/EAD/EDisciplinas/Forum/1

Alguem pode me ajudar?
Estou programando em C# asp.net MVC 5

Comment: Tenta fazer assim ./EAD/EDisciplinas/Forum/@ViewBag.IDDisciplina',

Comment: Continua criando o link assim: http://localhost:32322/EAD/EDisciplinas/Index/EAD/EDisciplinas/Forum/1

Comment: E SEM O PONTO? /EAD/EDisciplinas/Forum/@ViewBag.IDDisciplina

Comment: Se o ponto foi amigo. Obrigado. Coloque como resposta por favor,para que eu possa marcar. Obrigado mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Coloca assim.

```
$(function()
{
    /* Atribui ID */
    $("#itemsA").attr("href", "@ViewBag.IDDisciplina");
    /* CRIA A HREF */
    $('<a>', {
        class: 'item dalink',
        href: '/EAD/EDisciplinas/Forum/@ViewBag.IDDisciplina',
        text: 'Forum de Discussão'
    }).appendTo('.firstmenu');
});
```